# Video Tutorials Website with different Packages in Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, video, web

I am new to wordpress and i have a project of video tutorials website in wordpress where under different packages, different number of videos will be allocated and after purchasing, the user will be able to view them. I have built normal e-commerce websites but don't know how to make this website. Please guide me if any plugin is available and i can use it. Thank you so much..

Answer (score 0):

> **With [WooCommerce](https://woocommerce.com/) you are good to go. I believe It's the perfect ecommerce plugin for WordPress.**

WooCommerce comes with a [feature](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/digital-downloadable-product-handling/#) for digital or downloadable product (tutorial video in your case), where the user can be forced to sign in, complete the order and pay before downloading the content. After completing the order, content will be always available for download in that user account.

Note that [product bundles](https://sk.wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-product-bundles/) are also available for WooCommerce as **YITH WooCommerce Product Bundles** plugin.

---

You can simply create a product for each video and a bundle of products for each tutorial (as seen on screenshot). You can set which product bundles will be shown on website.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much.. Its really helpful but how to create different packages and how can i assign videos under different packages ?

Comment: updated plugin link, where the plugin is also well documented; updated answer with screenshot explaining how to assign videos under different packages.

Comment: First you need to create a product for each video for first tutorial. Than create **another product** and under Product Data (see screenshot) select that it's going to be a **Product Bundle**

Comment: thanks for all the information. It has really helped me.. :)